# git checkout -f staging fatal: cannot create directory at 'public/C:\xamppphp8\htdocs\caab-hcc\storage\logs': Invalid argument

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket

I am try to checkout git checkout -f staging  this way from widows PowerShell  (my operating system is **windows 10** )

```
git checkout -f staging
```

> git checkout -q --track origin/staging
> fatal: cannot create directory at 'public/C:\xamppphp8\htdocs\caab-hcc\storage\logs': Invalid argument

I can check out other branch easily from same repository but when I am going to use **Staging branch** i am  getting this error

**its Laravel project**

```
    > git for-each-ref --format %(refname:short)%00%(upstream:short) refs/heads
> git checkout -q --track origin/staging
fatal: cannot create directory at 'public/C:\xamppphp8\htdocs\caab-hcc\storage\logs': Invalid argument
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/bangla_inpout_field_with_new_api refs/remotes/bangla_inpout_field_with_new_api
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\xamppphp8\htdocs\caab-hcc-1\.git\refs\remotes\origin\bangla_inpout_field_with_new_api', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
```

**Without -f flag**

```
git checkout staging
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        bootstrap/cache/config.php
        bootstrap/cache/packages.php
        bootstrap/cache/routes-v7.php
        bootstrap/cache/services.php
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Comment: What happens when you ommit the `-f` flag? Have you tried a different terminal like Git bash?

Comment: git checkout -f  staging
fatal: cannot create directory at 'public/C:\xamppphp8\htdocs\caab-hcc\storage\logs': Invalid argument   when i add -f  it`s same @EricLandheer

Comment: Something has gone wrong with the path name here: `public/C:\xampphp8` should certainly not begin with `public/C:`. I don't know what caused that, though. @EricLandheer: the `-f` flag is a red herring, although using `-f` in a checkout command is generally unwise.

Comment: @torek Removing the `-f` flag might cause a different error to show and therefore might provide valuable information to solving the problem. In this case, probably a red herring indeed.

Comment: @EricLandheer  git checkout staging
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        bootstrap/cache/config.php
        bootstrap/cache/packages.php
        bootstrap/cache/routes-v7.php
        bootstrap/cache/services.php
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting

Comment: @ShakilHossain I have provided an answer to your problem, see below.

Answer (score 0):

The error already tells you the problem. You have made changes in your current branch, that will be overwritten by checking out the `staging` branch.

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Remove the changes in your current branch (`git checkout .`) **You will lose your changes.**

If you want to also remove added files and you do not care about losing progress, use: `git reset --hard;`
`git clean -df`

2. Use `git stash` to stash your changes. Your stash can be re-applied at a later point.

Afterwards, `git checkout staging` should work again.

Comment: When I was in master branch  I run         git reset --hard      AND THEN         git clean -df    AND THEN  git checkout staging      Output :  fatal: cannot create directory at 'public/C:\xamppphp8\htdocs\caab-hcc\storage\logs': Invalid argument

Comment: @ShakilHossain I think a directory/file in the staging branch of this repository is causing this issue. It seems unrelated to Git. Unfortunately, this is impossible to tell without seeing the repository.

Perhaps remove the directory/file from the repository that is causing problems?